# Transform MySQL Query in HTML Form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have that query:

```
SELECT P.dt_venda as venda, 
SUM(CASE WHEN P.id_consultor = 4 THEN IR.receita_gerada_receita END) as consultor4,
SUM(CASE WHEN P.id_consultor = 3 THEN IR.receita_gerada_receita END) as funcionario3,
SUM(CASE WHEN P.id_consultor = 2 THEN IR.receita_gerada_receita END) as funcionario2
FROM item_receitas as IR, funcionarios as F, pedidos as P
WHERE P.id_consultor = F.id
AND IR.id_pedido = P.id
GROUP BY venda, F.nome
```

The result is this:
[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aM7p.png)

Now I need help how i can build a HTML form like those image.
Remember - The fields names are dynamics, can be funcionario5,funcionario6...

Comment: I don't understand why you'd construct such a convoluted query in MySQL, to then go and parse the result in php

Comment: @Strawberry , Thanks. I made another query and now i builded table perfectly.